# Warning in Jmeter log

Tags: shell, jmeter, windows-shell

im performancetesting a site with Jmeter that is on an internal environment. However we also have a company proxy which i have configured in the HTTP default request manager in Jmeter.

Now everything works fine, however i keep seeing these WARNINGS in the jmeter.log when im tailing at runtime. 
Everytime a thread starts up i see:

2014/02/07 15:35:46 WARN  - org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestProxyAuthentication: NEGOTIATE authentication error: Invalid name provided (Mechanism level: Could not load configuration file C:\WINDOWS\krb5.ini (Het systeem kan het opgegeven bestand niet vinden)) 
2014/02/07 15:35:48 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: *Mythread* 1-4

Does anyone know what this means, and if it is going to cause any problems. Ive tried setting the proxy credentials in like every possible place but it doesnt seem to matter.

Regards,

Johan

Comment: noone is familiar with these warnings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can ignore these messages unless you are testing application which uses [Kerberos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerberos_%28protocol%29) authentication. If you want it to go away - read below for explanation of what's happening and how to get rid of it.

The warning is for missing Kerberos configuration file in the default location. If you need to test application which assumes Kerberos login, you need to properly configure `krb5.conf` and `jaas.conf` files in /bin folder of your JMeter installation. If you're changing application module name in jaas.conf make sure that the same value is present in `jmeter.properties` or `user.properties` file as `kerberos_jaas_application` property. You can also specify the property during JMeter startup as `-J` parameter, i.e.

```
jmeter -Jkerberos_jaas_application=testapp -n -t myscript.jmx -l myscript.jtl
```

and make sure that following two system properties are set:

```
-Djava.security.krb5.conf=krb5.conf
-Djava.security.auth.login.config=jaas.conf
```

the paths given are relative to JMeter home folder, you might want to use full paths. See [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](http://blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) for more details on how to play with JMeter properties.

Also make sure that you set "Implementation" dropdown to **HTTPClient4** in [HTTP Request Defaults](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request_Defaults) (or for each HTTP Sampler)

Hope it makes sense

Comment: thanks, yes it makes sense. Thankfully my application does not need this, but this might be useful information for the future.